# wxButton - change position using C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm doing some experimental coding on Code::Blocks with wxSmith.

I have 2 buttons. When one is clicked, I want to change the position of the other.

I've tried this:

```
void FormButtons::OncmdMoveClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    cmd.pos.x += 10;
}
```

But I think it's not correct. According to the docs, I am supposed to be able to access wxPoint->X but I'm not quite sure how this is achieved.

Thanks for any tips.

EDIT: 
Sorry for the lack of info. **cmd** and **cmdMove** are **wxButton**.

Comment: @ravenspoint Sorry about that. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems odd that you have a reference to a widget - usually you have a pointer.

Anyhow, you need to move the button by calling a method called, strangely enough, Move.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#ab1cb98c8d25b9e6ff7b706b1446c3df7

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. It gave me some direction and in the mean time I tried something through mere trial and error. I shall post that as well.

Comment: Yes, I know now :) but I was kind of misled because I was looking for the wxButton's docs here: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxbutton.html and it was so restricted.

Comment: After all, I was looking to move the button and not the form :) so it was only natural that I looked in there. I never thought they'd put it under wxWindow (yes I see there's a relationship)

Answer (score -1):

STRANGELY, I could not find sufficient info on the docs. Perhaps I'm overlooking something. But in the mean time, I bumped into [this article](http://nullege.com/codes/search/wx.Button.SetPosition) that is about Python and I did a bit of guess-work and came up with this method...

```
cmd->SetPosition( wxPoint( cmd->GetPosition().x + 10,100));
```

It works great and does what I need. But I find the answer by ravenspoint to be easier. I wonder how we can find out the methods of an object/class when we don't have any docs on them. Also my Code::Blocks IDE does not give any support on it. At least an object/class browser would be super-helpful :)

Comment: "we don't have any docs on them"  There exists extensive docs on all the widgets.  See the link I provided in my answer.

Comment: There are several functions you can use to set a button's position. Like most GUI frameworks, it's a BIG API, so it takes some digging to get to what you need. In general, the easiest way to find documentation is to look at the doc in question (in this case https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_button.html), then expand all the "public member functions inheritedfrom" (from bottom to top so it's easier), then use CTRL+F to find the function you need. Cheers!